# Is there a way to specify dispersion parameter in glmer (binomial family)?

Tags: glm

I am trying to get estimates and standard errors from a glmer model. Once I know the disersion parameter I want to call summary and get the information. Is there a way to do it?

*EDITED*: I have seen that you can do what I want for glm with this code: summary(model, dispersion = 2.5) for model inference. However, it does not work for glmer models.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used binomial distribution and logit link function to fit a glmer model. I checked for overdispersion using dispersion_glmer() function. My dispersion parameter is 2.8. I added an observation level random effect term (OLRE) to the model. It corrects the overdispersion but then, the fitted. vs. residuals plot look very biased. Therefore, I want to run the previous models (without OLRE) and directly call summary of the model correcting the standards errors. I wonder if there is a way to tell the model that you already know the dispersion parameter so that it corrects standards errors.